# Can't run tor. Please help!

Tags: help

```
14.05.2016 14:00:28.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
14.05.2016 14:00:28.600 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\Îëüãà\Downloads\TorBrowserPortable\App\TorBrowser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
14.05.2016 14:00:29.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
14.05.2016 14:00:29.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
14.05.2016 14:00:29.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
14.05.2016 14:00:29.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
14.05.2016 14:00:29.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
14.05.2016 14:00:31.100 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (server '131.188.40.189:443'): It seems that our clock is behind by 1 hours, 0 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
14.05.2016 14:00:31.100 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
14.05.2016 14:00:32.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
14.05.2016 14:00:33.300 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time (server '199.254.238.52:443'): It seems that our clock is behind by 1 hours, 0 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings. 
14.05.2016 14:00:33.300 [WARN] Our clock is 59 minutes, 27 seconds behind the time published in the consensus network status document (2016-05-14 11:00:00 UTC).  Tor needs an accurate clock to work correctly. Please check your time and date settings! 
14.05.2016 14:00:33.300 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
14.05.2016 14:01:30.800 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
14.05.2016 14:02:31.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
14.05.2016 14:03:32.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
14.05.2016 14:08:37.400 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no recent usable consensus. 
14.05.2016 14:08:41.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
14.05.2016 14:08:41.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
14.05.2016 14:08:41.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
14.05.2016 14:08:42.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```